# Is it safe to publish my development private key?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, key-management, secret-sharing

For my development environment, the following three SSL files allow me to access my application from https://localhost on my local machine.

1. Private key: `server.key`
2. Certificate signing request: `server.csr`
3. Self-signed certificate: `server.crt`

Is it safe to publish these files (publicly) to Github?

Of course, for the production environment, I'd use different SSL files and keep them private.

Comment: Implementation Details: [localhost SSL with puma](https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075)

Comment: It depends on if you are okay with everyone having access to the server.  But...malicious actors may also be able to pretend to be your server using your private key, and redirect users elsewhere.  I think you need to keep the private key to yourself.

Comment: @StoneTrue what server? I run the application from my local machine.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale why not just not sync those files?

Comment: Local host only - okay.  Make sure it is never outward facing.  Why would you need to put the key on Github in that case?  Seems like having the key to a closet in my house under the front door mat...

Comment: Why? So that other developers can run the application locally and access it from `https://localhost` on their local machines (without having to recreate all those files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in case you will be using different SSL key, cert, and request in final solution. There no need to worry about publish them online.