# Do .crt and .key files contain sensitive information?

Tags: tls

Some of my end-to-end tests require making calls to a **mock** https server, so I've written a very basic one in JavaScript and generated `.crt` and `.key` files for it on my employer's computer.

Now my employer asks to open-source the project. This would mean publishing both files to a public repository. Naturally, some members of the team questioned the contents of `.crt` and `.key` files.

Do `.crt` and `.key` files contain sensitive information? Is it safe to publish them in my specific case?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/what-is-the-difference-between-pem-csr-key-and-crt  Have you opened them to see? Do you know that the `key` file is a private key? Are you ok with publishing that?

Comment: @schroeder yes, there's a lot of characters, but I don't know what they represent and how they were generated. I'm okay with publishing the private key due to the reasons I explained in the question.

Comment: sometimes even mock servers need protection, so I needed to ask - you can use certificate parsers to see what data might be encoded: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Comment: I've just found a similar question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106125

Answer (score 8):

The `.crt` file embeds the public key and could theoretically be published. The `.key` is the private key and should not be published.

Ideally, you don't want to publish any certificates at all, and add a notice for users of the project on how to generate/get their own certificates.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but I like the proposed workaround. +1 from me. I'm now using [create-cert](https://github.com/lukechilds/create-cert) to generate a self-signed certificate on the fly and there's no need to commit and publish the files anymore.

Comment: @Oleg this is the far better solution

Comment: Well, you could always put a pair of self-signed certificate files and use other one on your own server instance. But that could hurt people that aren't security savvy if they just use the project as is.

Answer (score 1):

the .crt and .key file contains that information you put into them.

- Addresses if defined
- Password of the private key (if you set one because you need it then in the mock server to decrypt it)
- other informations you put into it while creation

If you are ok with that, you **can** publish it. Better way is to generate a Key-Pair on the fly or tell in the documentation how to generate one that the mock server can use